# Subscribing to an Observable inside a callback function

Tags: angular, callback, rxjs, observable, auth0

I have the following code in my component:

```js
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  // Coming back from Auth0 social redirect
  this.authService.parseHash((error, result) => {
      if (result) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.callService(result.idTokenPayload.email, true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }
    } else if (error) {
      logError(error);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/alert');
    }
  });
}

private callService(email: string, goHome = false) {
  this.authService.createUser().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.validatedEmail = email;
      if (goHome) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      }
    },
    err => {
      logError(err);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/alert');
    }
  );
}
```

Even though `result` above does return a value, the window hash never gets cleared and the router never navigates to home. Why is that? Can I not subscribe to an observable (it's a simple post request) from within a callback function?

Comment: Can you comment call to this.callService method n check window.hash is clearing or not ?

Comment: Will do this now; just FYI I just debugged, and I found out that `router` actually showed up as undefined in Intellij's debugging extension for Chrome! Is that normal?